# My App icon is not appearing in imessage store panel

Tags: ios10, custom-keyboard, imessage, imessage-extension

[image: Refer to the image here :]

Icon for buzmessa.. is not appearing while i put all the required imessage icons in Assets and double checked that there sizes are proper as required.

Answer (score 1):

There could be few possibilities :

1. Check Whether icon size is proper or not.
2. Check whether Assets which u are using is properly set in project target.
   Let me know if u didn't able to find out the solution.

Comment: ya, 2nd one was the case.

Comment: For me, the problem was I only built my host app with target dependency on my extension. 
The solution was to run the extension target without the host target.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time solving this problem, none of the advice I found on the forums helped me. The problem was solved by updating the iOS version (in my case to 16.6.1.). But the ambiguity remains, I’ll continue to observe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).